# If there is no properties file declared, what does the $ do in an Ant build file?

Tags: ant, build

Essentially, I am wondering how ant knows that $ means to pull from the properties file.. what if there was no properties file named?

Take example this build file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Hello World Project" default="info">
<property file="build.properties"/>

 <fileset dir="${build.dir}" >
 <include name="**/*.java"/>
</fileset>

<target name="info">
<echo>${src}</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

I know that the $ sign is referencing a property in the build.properties file, however what if there is no properties file, what does the $ sign do in a regular Ant compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant leaves references to non-existent properties unchanged. For example, the following Ant script...

```
<project name="ant-echo-missing-property" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <property file="non-existent-file.properties"/>
        <echo>${missing-property}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

...outputs...

```
run:
     [echo] ${missing-property}
```

Comment: interesting, so what if you declare a property file outside of a target, say at the top of the antfile. Yet you declare another property file inside a target, will the $ take precedence to the one outside the target?

Comment: Tasks outside of `<target>` elements are evaluated before tasks inside of `<target>` elements. In Ant, the first task to set a property "wins". Properties in Ant are immutable; they cannot be changed after they are first set.

Comment: Okay, and one more question, What if you have multiple property files declared at the top of the ant file. Now inside of a task if you reference a variable say ${exists-in-one-file} will ANT know which file to find to grab that value or will there be a discrepancy??

Comment: Yes, Ant can handle the case of multiple property files. Ant will process each property file in the order they are listed in the Ant script. The first property file with `${exists-in-one-file}` in it will determine the value of the property.